# Parsing custom if statement input in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, lexer, if-statement

I'm working on a feature where users can get data based on the if statement they write. The if statement looks something like the excel's conditionals.

**Basic syntax:**

`IF ( lhs == rhs, ifTrue, ifFalse)`

**Examples:**

`IF ( (2 + 2 - (2 * 1)) == 2, "Equal!", 0)`

`IF ( "ABC" > "a", IF (1 == 1, 100, 200) , 0)`

`IF ( "hello world" == concat("hello ", "world"), $myVar$, 0)`

**Note**: There can be nested if statements/expressions and variables are identified by `$` wrapper. Example: `$var$`

**What I've tried so far:**

- Using Regular Expressions and string manipulation but I realized that it won't hold when the statement gets complex.
- Using [Doctrine Lexer](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/lexer.html) package to breakdown the statement into tokens as per the grammar. This helps in identifying the type of tokens but doesn't help in checking if the statement is syntactically correct or how to evaluate the expressions.

**Question**

How do I go about parsing the statements correctly, checking if the syntax is correct and evaluate them?

**Lexer code, for reference:**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\Common\Lexer\AbstractLexer;

class Lexer extends AbstractLexer
{
// All tokens that are not valid identifiers must be < 100
public const T_NONE              = 1;
public const T_INTEGER           = 2;
public const T_STRING            = 3;
public const T_INPUT_PARAMETER   = 4;
public const T_FLOAT             = 5;
public const T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS = 6;
public const T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS  = 7;
public const T_COMMA             = 8;
public const T_DIVIDE            = 9;
public const T_MODULUS           = 10;
public const T_DOT               = 11;
public const T_EQUALS            = 12;
public const T_GREATER_THAN      = 13;
public const T_LESSER_THAN       = 14;
public const T_LESSER_THAN_EQUAL = 15;
public const T_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL= 16;
public const T_MINUS             = 17;
public const T_MULTIPLY          = 18;
public const T_NEGATE            = 19;
public const T_PLUS              = 20;
public const T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACE  = 21;
public const T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE = 22;

// All tokens that are identifiers or keywords that could be considered as identifiers should be >= 100
public const T_ALIASED_NAME         = 100;
public const T_FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME = 101;
public const T_IDENTIFIER           = 102;
public const T_VARIABLE             = 103;
public const T_FUNCTION             = 104;

// All keyword tokens should be >= 200
public const T_ALL      = 200;
public const T_ELSE     = 215;

/**
 * Creates a new query scanner object.
 *
 * @param string $input A query string.
 */
public function __construct($input)
{
    $this->setInput($input);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getCatchablePatterns()
{
    return [
        '[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*\:[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*(?:\\\[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)*', // aliased name
        '[a-z_\\\][a-z0-9_]*(?:\\\[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)*', // identifier or qualified name
        '(?:[0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]+)*)(?:e[+-]?[0-9]+)?', // numbers
        "'(?:[^']|'')*'", // quoted strings
        '\?[0-9]*|:[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*', // parameters
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getNonCatchablePatterns()
{
    return ['\s+', '(.)'];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getType(&$value)
{
    $type = self::T_NONE;

    switch (true) {
        // Recognize numeric values
        case (is_numeric($value)):
            if (strpos($value, '.') !== false || stripos($value, 'e') !== false) {
                return self::T_FLOAT;
            }

            return self::T_INTEGER;

        // Recognize quoted strings
        case ($value[0] === "'"):
            $value = str_replace("''", "'", substr($value, 1, strlen($value) - 2));

            return self::T_STRING;                

        // Recognize identifiers, aliased or qualified names
        case (ctype_alpha($value[0]) || $value[0] === '_' || $value[0] === '\\'):
            $name = strtoupper($value);

            if (defined($name)) {
                $type = constant($name);

                if ($type > 100) {
                    return $type;
                }
            }

            if (preg_match('/[a-z]+[ ]*(\((?:`[()]|[^()]|(?1))*\))/', $value[0], $match) !== FALSE){
                return self::T_FUNCTION;
            }

            if (strpos($value, ':') !== false) {
                return self::T_ALIASED_NAME;
            }

            if (strpos($value, '\\') !== false) {
                return self::T_FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME;
            }

            return self::T_IDENTIFIER;

        // Recognize input parameters
        case ($value[0] === '?' || $value[0] === ':'):
            return self::T_INPUT_PARAMETER;

        // Recognize symbols
        case ($value === '.'):
            return self::T_DOT;
        case ($value === ','):
            return self::T_COMMA;
        case ($value === '('):
            return self::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS;
        case ($value === ')'):
            return self::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS;
        case ($value === '='):
            return self::T_EQUALS;
        case ($value === '>'):
            return self::T_GREATER_THAN;
        case ($value === '<'):
            return self::T_LESSER_THAN;
        case ($value === '+'):
            return self::T_PLUS;
        case ($value === '-'):
            return self::T_MINUS;
        case ($value === '*'):
            return self::T_MULTIPLY;
        case ($value === '/'):
            return self::T_DIVIDE;
        case ($value === '%'):
            return self::T_MODULUS;
        case ($value === '!'):
            return self::T_NEGATE;
        case ($value === '{'):
            return self::T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACE;
        case ($value === '}'):
            return self::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE;
        case ($value === '$'):
            return self::T_VARIABLE;

        // Default
        default:
            // Do nothing
    }

    return $type;
}
```

Comment: There are many lexing/grammar packages out there. You simply need to search for them. I found reading [Crafting Interpreters](http://craftinginterpreters.com/) to be quite helpful in general.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Thank you for the recommendation, will give it a read. As mentioned above, I am using Doctrine Lexer for lexing, it's the next steps that I don't know of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a clean refactoring of an If Else Code without leaving any free blocks?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220888/how-to-do-a-clean-refactoring-of-an-if-else-code-without-leaving-any-free-blocks)

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim, the next step is to create a parser that can tell from a set of tokens if they form a valid construct in your language and what that construct means.

Comment: The canonical reference here is the [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I tried to check if the tokens are valid by looping through each one. But the possibilities are too many. There can be nested expressions, strings, functions, variables, etc. at any location. I guess maybe my way of validating was wrong

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim: You should research the topic of parsers. Your way of validation was most likely too simplistic, because the language you described should pose no problem at all for a parser.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Is it possible to build an abstract syntax tree from tokens?

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim: Yes, that is exactly the job of a parser.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks, will try